Wigner-Weyl distribution
I'm studying the topic of quantum optics and am now busy studying the different representations on how we can only look at the diagonal elements of the density operator in the coherent states basis (like the P-representation, Q-representation or Wigner,...). The Wigner-Weyl distribution can be used to determine the expectation values of symmetrically order operators and I'm asked to show that
$$\frac{<\hat{a}^{\dagger}\hat{a} + \hat{a}\hat{a}^{\dagger}>}{2} = \int W(\alpha, \alpha^*)|\alpha|^2d\alpha$$
I know these expectation values can be determined by used the trace over the density matrix operator, so
$$\frac{<\hat{a}^{\dagger}\hat{a} + \hat{a}\hat{a}^{\dagger}>}{2} = \frac{1}{2}Tr(\rho(\hat{a}^{\dagger}\hat{a} + \hat{a}\hat{a}^{\dagger}))$$
However i do not seem to know on how we can rewrite this rho to get to the Wigner-Weyl distribution.
