Wigner-weyl distribution in quantum optics by scully & zubairy
I have a question concerning an equation in the book of scully & Zubairy on quantum optics. The equation is the following
$$<a^{\dagger}> = \Big[\frac{\partial}{\partial(i\beta)}+\frac{\beta^*}{2i}\Big]C^{(s)}(\beta,\beta^*)|_{\beta^* = \beta = 0}$$
where
$$C^{(s)}(\beta,\beta^*) = Tr(e^{i\beta^*\alpha+i\beta\alpha^*}\rho)$$
I know that i can write
$$<a^{\dagger}> = Tr(\rho a^{\dagger}) = Tr\Big(\rho\frac{1}{\pi}\int d\alpha|\alpha><\alpha |a^{\dagger}\Big) = \frac{1}{\pi}\int <\alpha|\rho|\alpha> \alpha^*$$
However i can't seem to get this wigner represention formalism inside of it, so can anybody help me with this:((

Previous post by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/838316/
